# Unable to disable keyboard popup on select2 open event

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm working on select2 for mobile device. It's working fine, however, when select drop down is opened, the keyboard pops up as well, as demonstrated below:

[image]

I tried to disable it, by setting lose focus on search box on select-open event as below:

```
$('select').on('select2:open',function(){
    alert('open');
    $('input.select2-search__field').blur();
})
```

But it seemed it does not work, the keyboard still pops up.

Is there any way or built-in option of select2 to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

try `e.preventDefault()` inside the click handler when select2 is clicked

Comment: Select2 will not be triggering the native events (https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1908#issuecomment-76546178), therefore, this does not work. Thanks very much